# Why are two HTTP requests blocking each other in Firefox (according to Firebug)

Tags: http, firefox, networking, firebug

I have a simple webpage (at least initially) that contains (in this order):

1. A single link to some CSS in the
2. An **inline** script in the  (to set the dojoConfig settings for dojo)
3. A script tag linking to external javascript

The top 3 entries shown in the timeline [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14930473/Screenshots/Firebug%20timeline.png) are for the HTML page itself, the CSS, and the external javascript.  (The stuff below all comes after the "onload" event, and happens afterwards)

**Why** does Firefox appear to be blocking the request for the javascript until the request for the CSS has completed?  My page only has two things to load at this stage, and I would expect the browser to load them in parallel.

Comment: A full screenshot with the URLs etc would probably be useful.

Comment: All of the URLs are to the same host, port, and all over https.  Why would the URLs matter when so few requests are involved?

Comment: Which version of Firefox is this?  Anything at all recent will in fact speculatively prefetch the external script in this situation...

Comment: Boris, see http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network&v=top it looks like Firefox regressed in version 20 for the test "CSS + Inline Script", which is similar to this scenario